# PayPal Authorization Header

Tags: paypal

I was able to successfully generate an Access Token and TokenSecret for a test paypal account. However the next step is to create the Authorization Header for calls.

In this case, I need to supply an Oauth Signature or API Signature I'm not sure. In this case, do I generate the signature from my Access Token and Secret somehow?

If not, can I use my (not the merchant I'm requesting permissions from) API signature? or do I have to use theirs?

Thank you for the help.

Edit:In addition, if I do have to get the signature or credentials from the merchant. Then would I always have to tell them to fetch their api credentials first?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using one of the PayPal SDK's you will just have to pass the Access Token and Access Token Secret to the Service via their set methods. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466878/4320911) is an example using the Invoicing SDK.

To answer the second part of your question, you will have to provide the merchants(3rd party of whom you requested permission from) PayPal email address. For example, if you were sending an invoice you would set the sender as the merchant(whom which you requested permission from) and the recipient as the person who you are hoping to send the invoice to(PayPal email address). Again code in the link above demonstrates this.